# emacs how to toggle ido-find-file and find-file(without ido)

Tags: emacs

Just like the title. I know **C-f** can change **ido-find-file** to **find-file**(without ido).

But when in **find-file**(without ido), I want to turn back to **ido-find-file**, I can't find any method can do that.

So, how to toggle to **ido-find-file** when in **find-file**(without ido)